# overload *= operator for matrices c++

Tags: c++, matrix, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the *= operator for matrices This is my function for the * operator for 2 matrices

```
    template <class T>
    Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*(const Matrix& other) const
    {
        assert(cols == other.rows) ;

        Matrix<T> temp(rows, other.cols) ;

        for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
        {
            for(unsigned j = 0 ; j < other.cols ; j++)
            {
                temp.matrix[i][j] = 0 ;
                for(unsigned k= 0 ; k < other.rows ; k++)
                {
                    temp.matrix[i][j] = temp.matrix[i][j] + (matrix[i][k]*other.matrix[k][j]) ;
                }
            }
        }
        return temp ;
    }
```

Here is my *= operator implementation

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator*=(const Matrix& other) const 
{
    assert(cols == other.rows) ;


    for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned j = 0 ; j < other.cols ; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 0 ;
            for(unsigned k= 0 ; k < other.rows ; k++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + (matrix[i][k]*other.matrix[k][j]) ;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this ;
}
```

I can't figure out where the semantic errors are in my *= implementation because it compiles and runs but the output is way above what is expected

Comment: In `operator*` you have a temporary lhs matrix that you initialise to 0, but in `operator*=` you are actually initialising the real lhs matrix to 0, meaning you lose its current value.

Comment: Why just don't `*this = *this * other`?

Comment: Depending on how you store `matrix`, you're probably going to have to make a new container anyway because of the size change. Could you just copy the returned matrix of a `operator*` call within the `operator*=` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot assign the result of the product to one of the terms while still evaluating it, since that will destroy the original values you still need to calculate the other elements.

Since you have a working binary `*`, the simple way to implement `*=` is to make it as `*this = *this * other`.

There can be shortcuts, but requires matrices to have particular structure (diagonals, triangular an similar). In the general case, that's the simpler and safer way.

Of course I assume you matrices are at least copyable and assignable. And if even also movable, you can gain performance too.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the LHS of the operator while still trying to compute the product.

Take the matrices:

```
1  0
0  1
```

and

```
2 0 
0 2
```

For `i = 0` and `j = 0`, you end of making the first matrix;

```
0  0
0  1
```

before you start the multiplication. You know you are not going to get the right answer after that.

I don't know if there is a technique you can use to multiply the two matrices and keep the resultant in the LHS (or the RHS).